# Bash: read file line by line, split line, pass as an command line arg

Tags: bash, file, split, line, command-line-interface

I am reading a test.txt file. Format:

```
79033d0135a21e45c60e283785f5914b
dde8d97a40cd22667ccb3ca972197586
4fd5ea73cd51db256384fb3333b0eb3d
```

I am reading this file line by line and splitting as (eg. line 1: 79 03 3d 01 35 a2 1e 45 c6 0e 28 37 85 f5 91 4b)

The bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    a="$line" | cut -c1-2
    b="$line" | cut -c3-4
    c="$line" | cut -c5-6
    d="$line" | cut -c7-8
    e="$line" | cut -c9-10
    f="$line" | cut -c11-12
    g="$line" | cut -c13-14
    h="$line" | cut -c15-16
    i="$line" | cut -c17-18
    j="$line" | cut -c19-20
    k="$line" | cut -c21-22
    l="$line" | cut -c23-24
    m="$line" | cut -c25-26
    n="$line" | cut -c27-28
    o="$line" | cut -c29-30
    p="$line" | cut -c31-32
    #./a.out "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" "$e" "$f" "$g" "$h" "$i" "$j" "$k" "$l" "$m" "$n" "$o" "$p"
    echo "$line"
    echo "$a $b $c $d $e $f $g $h $i $j $k $l $m $n $o $p"
done < test_10.txt
```

For now I am just trying to print the variables. I intend to pass them as a command line arg to my C++ program later.

The problem is, I am not able to print the variables. Of course my C++ program could not take arguments as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need command substitution, `$()`, (and also `echo`):

```
a=$(echo "$line" | cut -c1-2)
```

Here the STDOUT of the command `echo "$line" | cut -c1-2` will be saved as variable `a`.

Instead of creating an anonymous pipe, you can use a here string, `<<<` to pass the variable content:

```
a=$(cut -c1-2 <<<"$line")
```

Now pick any method, and apply the same for all others.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can you please explain the second solution? I mean what do you mean by anonymous pipeline?

Comment: @algoProg `|` is called anonymous pipe, necessarily with `echo "$line" | cut -c1-2`, you are needing one extra process `echo`, and one pipe which are not needed in second one as `<<<` is handled internally by shell.

Comment: Clear! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the pipe to work as you intend, the contents of `$line` need to get to `stdin`, such as via an `echo`.

Additionally, you will need to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) with backticks or `$()` (the latter being the preferred method) to set the variable to the results of the command, otherwise it will attempt to evaluate the output of `echo "$line" | cut -c1-2` as a command itself, likely giving you a `command not found` error.

For example, your first assignment should be

```
a=$(echo "$line" | cut -c1-2)
```

And the others would follow a similar pattern.